# Show number of category posts in WordPress custom menu

Tags: wordpress

I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this issue. What I want to know is how to add show_count function of wp_list_categories in WordPress custom menu navigation under Appearances > Menu? Is it even possible to include number of posts inside of a category if added that category is added in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to override the `WP_Nav_Walker`.  Can't remember off the top of my head, but it's similar to how [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-posts-in-custom-menu/) works ([source](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/category-posts-in-custom-menu/trunk/category-posts-in-custom-menu.php)).

Some reading:

- http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output
- http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/